# How to search for a specific date after converting the date into a timestamp and storing it in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I get timeInMillis of calendar, and store it into SQLite.

My code is as follows:

```
fun insertExerciseModel(exerciseModel: ExerciseModel) {
    val exerciseContentValue = ContentValues()
    ...
    exerciseContentValue.put(Contract.ExerciseEntry.CALENDAR, exerciseModel.calendar.timeInMillis)
    ...
    writableDatabase.insert(
        Contract.ExerciseEntry.TABLE_NAME_EXERCISE,
        null,
        exerciseContentValue
    )

    ...
}
```

I can search all row from table and order by calendar.

```
SELECT * FROM Contract.ExerciseEntry.CALENDAR ORDER BY calendar
```

However, the data is `INTEGER type` and it is timeInMillis.

How do I search for a specific date like January 8, 2020?

Or what command can I give after `WHERE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the `DATETIME` function to convert your table's milliseconds since epoch to an ISO datetime.  Then, just compare that against the date literal you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM Contract.ExerciseEntry.CALENDAR
WHERE
    DATETIME(ROUND(calendar / 1000), 'unixepoch') >= '2020-01-08' AND
    DATETIME(ROUND(calendar / 1000), 'unixepoch') <  '2020-01-09'
ORDER BY
    calendar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    try {
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy")
        val parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("January 8, 2020")
        // thats the value you will search for in the database
        // parsedDate.getTime();
    }catch (  e:java.lang.Exception){ //this generic but you can control another types of exception
// look the origin of excption
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the date from miliseconds with [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d', miliseconds / 1000, 'unixepoch')
```

so you need an sql statement like this:

```
val sql = "SELECT * FROM ${Contract.ExerciseEntry.CALENDAR} WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datecolumnname / 1000, 'unixepoch') = '2020-01-08'"
```